# IE8 cursor jumps to the end of a textarea when an UpdatePanel fires

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, updatepanel, textarea

I have an *UpdatePanel* and a textarea on a page like this:

```
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer" Interval="1000" OnTick="Tick" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanel" updatemode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label" runat="server" />          
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger controlid="Timer" eventname="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" Width="600" Height="400" TextMode="MultiLine" />

// Codebehind
protected void Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Label.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Whenever the *UpdatePanel* timer fires, the cursor in the textarea moves to the end of the text. If you try to add any text *to the middle* of the text area it becomes very difficult as the cursor keeps jumping to the end. This ***only*** happens in **IE8**. All other browsers are perfectly happy to let you type *in the middle* of the text without issue.

Any idea why this happens in IE and how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe IE8 has a known text area bug.

Try setting the min-width and max-width to be the same value.

Just to make sure, if you use Compatibility Mode, does this error occur?

```
textarea {
  width: 700px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

You might also want to set a fixed pixel `height` property.

Comment: It is happening in Compatibility mode with width, height, and min/max width all set. It is also happening in IE7, IE8, and quirks mode.

Comment: This issue is not the same as the page here: http://grantovich.net/misc/ie8-textarea-bug/. It occurs whether you are typing in the box or not. Simply putting the cursor anywhere in the box and waiting for the ajax timer will kick the cursor to the end.